# Scrape data with Beautiful Soup when its formatted differently in different situations

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape governor election data from the web, and I'm struggling with one part of it. So as you can see in the two cases, there are either two candidates (democratic or republican) or 3 candidates (dem, repub, independant).

I wrote the following code to scrape the data. This works for the 2 candidate situation, but i'm not sure how to make it work for both situations.

Here's my code:

```
html = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

#Scrape the percentage Numbers
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
table_row = table.find_all('tr')[1]
table_data = table_row.find_all('td')[3:5]
```

**CASE 1:**

[image]

**CASE 2:**

[image]

Comment: Please make the question clear about what results you want.

Comment: What does td with class spread contains. You want to ignore it in which condition.

Comment: currently my code works in Case 1, because it finds td's from [3:5], however in the second case i need [3:6]. I'm not sure how to write a piece of code that allows me to scrape in both of these situations

Comment: I was surprised to see that beautifulsoup can't do stuff like `td:not(.spread)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
table_row = table.find_all('tr')[1]
table_data = table_row.find_all('td')
if table_data[-1].class == 'spread': #checking whether the last td has class spread
    table_data = table_data[3:5]
else: 
    table_data = table_data[3:6]
```